# How to loop in Python-Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just gotten my first programming assignment of the semester; making a rock paper, scissors game that lasts until one player has won three times. I've managed to get it running, but I'm having trouble getting it to loop back to the beginning.

```
ps1 = 0
ps2 = 0


from random import radint
player1 = imput('R, P, S')

print (player1, " vs ", end='')
chosen = randint(1,3)
    #print (chosen)
if chosen == 1:
    player2 = 'R'
elif chosen == 2:
    player2 = 'P'
else:
    player2 = 'S'

print(player2)

if player1 == player2:
    print("Draw")
elif player1 == 'R' and player2 == 'S'
    ps1 = ps1 + 1
        print("Point to Player 1")
elif player1 == 'R' and player2 == 'P'
    ps2 = ps2 + 1
        print("Point to Player 2")
elif player1 == 'P' and player2 == 'S'
    ps2 = ps2 + 1
        print("Point to Player 2")
elif player1 == 'P' and player2 == 'R'
    ps1 = ps1 + 1
        print("Point to Player 1")
elif player1 == 'S' and player2 == 'R'
    ps2 = ps2 + 1
        print("Point to Player 2")
elif player1 == 'S' and player2 == 'P'
    ps1 = ps1 + 1
        print("Point to Player 1")
if ps1 = 3
    print("Player 1 wins!")
elif ps2 = 3
    print("Player 2 wins!")
```

Comment: [Try This](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+loops)

Answer (score 1):

You need a while loop that checks if there is a winner every time it starts over. And when you found a winner inside the loop, make the while condition False so that it won't loop again. Or just "break" as was reminded below.

Comment: yep. That's better

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a `random.randint` function for the random choice. You also dont need to import randint from random. You have to understand that `.randint()` is in the random library. Im not going to create every single control flow statement but here's a cleaned up base for your code

```
import random


def main():
    p2points = 0
    p1points = 0
    
    player1 = input('Please Pick Rock Paper or Scizzors!')
    gameList = ['Rock','Paper','Scizzors']
    chosen = random.choice(gameList)
    #print (chosen)
    print('\n%s vs %s'% (player1,chosen))
    
    #code

for i in range (3):
main()
```